# Unable to run main method in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When attempting to run the main method in IntelliJ I get the following error:

`Error:Cannot run program "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" (in directory "C:\Users\MyName\.IntelliJIdea2016.3\system\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

I'm not entirely sure what to do here, because I do have a JDK installed on my machine.

Comment: Does it help if you remove and add JSDK again in the Project Structure, then select it as the default for the project?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you have to do the JDK path 
go to the JDK directory in program files then go to bin folder copy the directory adress then. 
go to computer right click on it then property go to advance setting then click on environment variables then choose path then edit it  at the last of the sentence of path enter ; then paste the path we copied

Comment: I actually just downloaded the jdk again from oracle.

Comment: its not something wrong with the JDK i thin its something with in the code or the editor that you are using